# RegEx split/tokenize string when character within the string changes

Tags: c#, regex, string

Racking my brain on this one.
I have an string e.g. MON-123ABC/456 78#AbCd

What I want is an array or list as follows

```
[0] = MON
[1] = -
[2] = 123
[3] = ABC
[4] = /
[5] = 456
[6] =  ' '  (space character that is between 6 and 7 in the example string)
[7] = 78
[8] = #
[9] = A
[10] = b
[11] = C
[12] = d
```

I basically want to split any string input when there is a transition from one type of character (alpha, numeric, non-alpha/numeric, upper case to lower case) to another

Either RegExp or C# code will do.
I've got a simple regex 0+|(?<=([1-9]))(?=[1-9])(?!\1) but this only splits on numeric, my regex is not that good. I've played with some C# code to loop thro' the string but I have a problem with the transition between character types.

Example 2: Another example input string maybe 123qaz  ZBC/45678#Ab-Cd

It's spiting on each transition NOT the position that's the key.
In example 2 there are two spaces between z and Z by the way.
As I mentioned it's the transition between types that's the key.

Comment: will all your inputs keep this exact format?  If so, you probably just want to use Substring methods.  If there's any deviation, it could become very complex to parse.

Comment: I just edited before your comment, string could be any format. It's the transition between chars that's the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that doesn't use regular expressions.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitOnType(string str)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int previousType = -1;
    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        int type;
        if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z')
            type = 0;
        else if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z')
            type = 1;
        else if ('0' <= c && c <= '9')
            type = 2;
        else
            type = 3;

        if (previousType != -1 && type != previousType)
        {
            yield return builder.ToString();
            builder.Clear();
        }

        builder.Append(c);
        previousType = type;
    }

    if (builder.Length > 0)
        yield return builder.ToString();
}
```

Note that this will group all non-alphanumeric characters together per the description, but can be change to do any addition grouping just by adding additional `else if` clauses.

Comment: You could use `char.GetUnicodeCategory()` inplace of the `type` value and to categorise alpha/numbers (would allow for non-latin as well)

Comment: @AlexK. That could definitately replace the char comparisons in the if conditions, but not as the type as it would separate non-alphanumeric values up into more than one set.

Comment: Doesn't like multiple spaces in a string, see my example 2

Comment: @Rory are you saying you want each space to be returned as separate items?  This will return one string with two spaces in the that case.

Comment: Yes it works, my mistake, I have several unit tests and code everywhere at the moment, thank you

Answer (score 1):

A little bit uggly, split on this regex:

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[^a-z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[^A-Z])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[^0-9])|(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9])(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9])|(?<=[^a-z])(?=[a-z])|(?<=[^A-Z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[^0-9])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])
```

**Details:**

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[^a-z])                : split between lc alpha and not alpha
|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[^A-Z])               : or split between UC alpha and not alpha
|(?<=[0-9])(?=[^0-9])               : or split between digit and not digit
|(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9])(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9])   : or split between alphanum and not alphanum
|(?<=[^a-z])(?=[a-z])               : reverse of above
|(?<=[^A-Z])(?=[A-Z])
|(?<=[^0-9])(?=[0-9])
|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])
```

It gives me:

```
("MON", "-", 123, "ABC", "/", 456, " ", 78, "#", "A", "b", "C", "d")
```

Comment: Nearly. Thanks for the explanation btw . It misses out the #AbCd

Comment: @Rory: Strange, it works fine for me. BTW I didn't do it with C# but with Perl.

Comment: Yes, it does work, my mistake, thank you so much. Hope I've managed to vote up your answer

Comment: @Rory: You're welome,, glad it helps.

Answer (score 1):

How about `([A-Z]+|[a-z]+|\d+|[^\da-zA-Z]+)`

```
int i = 0;
foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(@"MON-123ABC/456 78#AbCd", @"([A-Z]+|[a-z]+|\d+|[^\da-zA-Z]+)"))
{
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", ++i, match.Groups[0]);
    }
}
```

For

```
1       MON
2       -
3       123
4       ABC
5       /
6       456
7
8       78
9       #
10      A
11      b
12      C
13      d
```

Comment: I get 27 tokens with this one

Comment: Ah, use matches not split as above.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=-|\/|\s|#)|(?<=-|\/|\s|#)|(?!\d)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[^\d])|(?<=[a-z])|(?=[a-z])
```

Try this.See demo.Replace by `\n`

http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/55

Comment: AbCd are tokenized into one group, should be 4 separate ones